# How to make imagebutton appear and textview center for toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, imagebutton

I have a tool bar with one icon on the left and one icon on the right. In the center will be a text view? Below is my current layout settings.

The problem now is the the imagebutton image is not appearing is just a small silver color rectangle appear and the text view words are aligning to left rather than center. Another thing how to control the height of the icon text view such that they look similar? The final icon on the right does not appear either too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height">

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pinButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:drawable="@drawable/basgreen"
    android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pinButton3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:drawable="@drawable/basgreen"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Below is the final screen shot of the output so far.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, use `src`, not use `drawable`

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pinButton"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:clickable="true"
android:background="@null" 
android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/basgreen" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pinButton3"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:clickable="true"
android:background="@null"
 android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/basgreen" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Its like one image comes partial and the other is so big and the texview gone missing.

Comment: must I set the ImageButton width and height so that it stay in tact?

Comment: You need to set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to fit `ImageButton `

Comment: if I use say 30dp as the width and height it is reasonable or too small ?

Comment: I tried this  android:layout_width="30dp"
and            android:layout_height="30dp" the box now turn to be white color rather

Comment: Post your `basgreen` drawable.

Comment: From Material Design Keylines Touch Target Size https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size , size for icons is 24dp

Comment: Add `android:background="@null" android:scaleType="centerInside" ` to your ImageButton

Comment: I have update the latest output can you advice what to improve ? I feel 24dp is a bit too small ? Another thing how to make the whole size toolbar smaller as I see space waster below. Also the icon are like a a bit too high do you think should I give some top padding.

Comment: You should generate your menu icon in link .It will generate multi icon relevant to your multi screens https://jgilfelt.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60

Comment: Why to generate using that tool? Cause it will build all the different resolution images is it? So should I do that for all my drawable images in res/drawable? Another thing how to scale down the tool bar height? I feel is a bit too big

Comment: I think you should ask another question for scale your image suitable with menu icon. I usually use this tool to generate icons for multi screen. if you read https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size, you will see icon is 48dp but the true icon is 24dp, it automatically generate these dimensions for you.

Comment: @I saw the link you suggested they mention about 48 dp but inside its only 24dp so should I make it 48dp cause my image is transparent with not background?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding weight

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottomToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:minHeight="@android:dimen/notification_large_icon_height">
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pinButton"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:android:gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/basgreen"
    android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dip"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pinButton3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/basgreen"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

It is because you are using `TextView`'s width as `match_parent`

Comment: still the same the icon image not appearing and the text is still align left

Comment: Yes I tried the exact codes its still the silver box like how I screen shot in my question too

Comment: post your basgreen did you try gravity instead of layout_gravity

Comment: you mean to say change the layout_grativity to just grativity?

Comment: Ok I trid just gravity it seems to come out but the image looks weird then I set the image as  android:layout_width="30dp" and    android:layout_height="30do" it turns into white box now.

Comment: Add `android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"` to your ImageButton

Comment: @RoShanShan does this apply to your coes to to Kiran's codes?

Comment: your problem is that image resolution is too high @user5313398

Comment: So what to do with the image?

Comment: you should test with another image temporarily now. then if it is worked then reduce the size of the image @user5313398

Comment: When you say reduce mean the size or redraw the image?

Comment: resolution with image asset tool in android studio

Comment: file->new-> image asset

Comment: This is to import in new image is it?

Comment: Yes but you can use this rename imported image @user5313398